# Parameter Dependency

Tags: tableau-api

I have a report with the following parameters: Start Date, End Date, Group 1, Group 2.  What I am trying to accomplish is to do a parameter dependency on Group 2 meaning if I select Group 1 parameter for Customer service, it will only show list of Group 2 parameter related to Customer service.

I tried to create a parameter for Customer Service and Sales then created a calculated field that when a value is selected Group 2 parameter is automatically refreshed, but epic fail. I created a calculated field using this code, but didn't work at all.  `IF [Group1] ="Customer Service" THEN [CS] ELSEIF [Group1]="Sales" THEN "SL" END` Note that the 'CS' and 'SL' are the parameters I created containing the Group 2 drop down list below.  Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like these need to be filters instead of parameters. Show the quick filter for Group 1. Show the filter for Group 2. In the Group 2 quick filter settings, choose Only Relevant Values. That way the group 2 will only list values based on what you select for group 1.

Comment: It is a filter driven by parameter. In SSRS when Parameter 1 values are selected Parameter 2 is automatically refreshed based on selection on Parameter 1

Comment: @Arsee so you need a solution that works in SSRS? I thought this was a Tableau question.

Comment: It is a tableau question. We are converting reports created in SSRS to tableau, and I am puzzled about parameter dependencies that we used in SSRS and wanted to know how to do it in Tableau.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely possible through CASE functions

Although note this about fields and parameters, parameters determine the fields or the values in the fields to show. You can't have a formula that returns a parameter

To me this doesn't make sense:

```
IF [Group1] ="Customer Service" THEN [CS] ELSEIF [Group1]="Sales" THEN "SL" END
```

The reason being that your THEN is a parameter, not a field

A simple way of doing this is:

1) You need 1 parameter for group 1 with string values for Customer Service and Sales

2) You then need to make a field for each value you want to group. Example of the field "IF [Group 2] CONTAINS("CS REGION") IS TRUE THEN [Group 2] END"

For the Sales field: "IF [Group 2] CONTAINS("Sales") IS TRUE THEN [Group 2] END"

Here is an example of the field to plug into the table using parameters that works correctly:

```
CASE [Group parameter]

WHEN "Customer Service" THEN "Group 2 CS field"
WHEN "Sales" THEN "Group 2 Sales field"

END
```